# How to dynamically update meta tags in Remix.run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meta-tags, remix.run

I just started to play with Remix.run and got stuck while trying to update the meta title :

```jsx
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const meta = () => {
  return [
    { title: "The count is: " },  // I want to show the count here
    { name: "description", content: "Count app" },
  ];
};

export default function Index() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <h1>The current count is : {count}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

How do I show the count in the meta title & keep synchronized the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may update page title with `document.title` from `useEffect` itself.

You may try something like this:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const meta = () => {
  return [
    {title: 'The count is: '}, // I want to show the count here
    {name: 'description', content: 'Count app'},
  ];
};

export default function Index() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
      document.title = `The count is: ${count + 1}`;
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>The current count is : {count}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

##### Edit 1:

You may also try like this:

```
// Another Approach
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `The count is: ${count + 1}`;
}, [count]);
```